# Breeze: how to prevent merge to happen

Tags: breeze

Having an entity in cache, that entity has related entities in the form of a top 20.
Now a user action can update the top 20 on the server, and I thus would like to redownload the entire entity. Server sends the correct data with top 20, but in Breeze, I end up with a top 40... And I can't figure out how to avoid this behavior.

Thanks for the tip

Update: I do not use odata webapi and iqueryable, as it offers too much power to clients for my app. So I don't want to use EntityQuery.fromEntityKey, which seems to do what I want. I'd prefer to keep using a "normal" query, to which I add a parameter.

Update 2: To add more clarity as to why I want to prevent merge, when I recompute the top 20, I delete all related entries in the db and recreate them, so they have new Id's. So I am now considering an update, which might actually solve my issue BUT I would still like to know if merge can be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

The Breeze EntityManager caches entities by primary key.  So presumably your 2nd query is returning a completely new set of entities with each query.  If this is the case, and you really only want the "latest" 20, the simplest fix would be to simply empty the EntityManager cache for this entity type before each query.  Something like:

```
var entities = myEntityManager.getEntities(myEntityType);
entities.forEach(function(e) {
   myEntityManager.detachEntity(e);
   // or
   // e.entityAspect.setDetached();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is exactly your qustion, but if you want to have different results on entity queries you may do it by creating 2 different controllers with different action names, or just with different parameters - overloaded methods. Then in your datacontext you can have 2 different queries.

You use .withParameters() propriety on the query to call the  controller method with parameters.

Then in the controller method you can query and filter  with LINQ, in any way you want. This way you can have different results based on the query/controller you chose to call.

Documentation: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/querying-depth